# Tool for database schema relationship, and routine relationship

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

what tool(s) do you use to draw database diagram for database rouintes relationship, e.g. tables, stored procedure, functions? Either commerical or free.

I am interested in both SQL Server and MySql.

Answer (score 1):

management studio and mysql workbench.

if you're not interested in diagrams, you can use heidisql for mysql

mssql has many features, you'll be amazed the more you discover. you can select a query, right click and click edit, and query builder opens for that selection. These are so useful that I'm forry for stallman fans.